# Space between two dynamic divs

Tags: css, html, web

So i am trying to get some kind of space between my two dynamic divs.
The space needs to be horizontal.
I want the right and the left div to change with the page width, but still have a space inbetween them.

The space needs to be transparent.

This is what i have now:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
#container {
height: 85px;
}

#left {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
float: left;
background: #0f0;
}

#right {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
float: right;
background: #0f0;
}

#spacer {
height: 100%;
width: 120px;
float: left;
background: #f00;
}
```

But this is all i get: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8Ss4/5/)

Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: need space between left and right class div s?

Comment: _the space needs to be transparent_. But you gave it a background color (`background: #f00;`), no wonder it is not transparent.

Comment: @Putvande The background on the spacer is just to see where it is. When it is in place, remove the background.

Comment: @SridharR Yes, but it should be horizontal space.

Comment: Just add some margins...

Comment: Maybe you should update the question so it is clear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#left,#right{
    width:calc(50% - 60px); //50% of width, minus 60px because spacer is of 120px
}
```

[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/R8Ss4/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set box-sizing to border-box and then simply add padding to the columns:

```
<div id="left">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

styles:

```
#left, #right {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 60px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
.content {
    background: #dfa;
}
```

Since padding is part of the column you must set the background to an inner element. The left and right columns will still be next to each other, but their content will be separated by transparent padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/FGuth/

More About border-box: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score -1):

Why not change left & right to 50% width, and apply negative margin:
http://jsfiddle.net/R8Ss4/7/

```
#container {
    height: 85px;
}
#left {
   height: 100%;
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
   margin-right: -60px;
   background: #0f0;
}    
#right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    float: right;
    background: #0f0;
}
#spacer {
   height: 100%;
   width: 120px;
   float: left;
   background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Your left and right column are still next to each other without any space in between (remove the background colour from the spacer and you will see).